# Como ouvir eventos sem abrir uma janela?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

Eu estou fazendo um simples projeto de *console* pessoal que vai fazer *keyboard hooking*, mas não quero que abra a janela OpenGL do SFML. Há como ouvir eventos do SFML sem abrir uma janela?

Comment: Se não me engano, para fazer keyboard hooking usando SFML você tem de abrir uma janela. Uma solucão seria utilizar uma thread comum para fazer a captura de teclas do teclado no próprio console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É apenas necessário ouvir o evento dentro de um thread. Em código genérico, por exemplo:

```
void callback()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(pressionado(tecla))
        {
            // o que for necessário
        }
    }
}
```

E depois a função é inserida em um thread.